# Is it possible that creating broadcast variables within spark streaming transformation function

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I tried to create a recoverable spark streaming job with some arguments got from database. But then I got a problem: it always gives me a serialization error  when I try to restart a job from checkpoint.

> 18/10/18 09:54:33 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 56.0 (TID 132) java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.util.SerializableConfiguration cannot be cast to
>   scala.collection.MapLike   at
>   com.ptnj.streaming.alertJob.InputDataParser$.kafka_stream_handle(InputDataParser.scala:37)
>   at
>   com.ptnj.streaming.alertJob.InstanceAlertJob$$anonfun$1.apply(InstanceAlertJob.scala:38)
>   at
>   com.ptnj.streaming.alertJob.InstanceAlertJob$$anonfun$1.apply(InstanceAlertJob.scala:38)
>   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:463)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:462)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)   at
>   org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:126)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282) 
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I followed the advice by maxime G in this [existing SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52553659/should-spark-broadcast-variables-type-be-number-or-string-when-i-try-to-restart), and it seems to help.

But now there is another exception. And because of that issue,I have to
create broadcast variables while stream transforming, like

```
 val kafka_data_streaming = stream.map(x => DstreamHandle.kafka_stream_handle(url, x.value(), sc))
```

So it going to be I have to put sparkcontext as a parameter into
transformation function, then it occurs:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108) 
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2094)   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$map$1.apply(DStream.scala:546)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$map$1.apply(DStream.scala:546)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:701)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.withScope(StreamingContext.scala:264)
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.map(DStream.scala:545)
>   at
>   com.ptnj.streaming.alertJob.InstanceAlertJob$.streaming_main(InstanceAlertJob.scala:38)
>   at com.ptnj.streaming.AlarmMain$.create_ssc(AlarmMain.scala:36)   at
>   com.ptnj.streaming.AlarmMain$.main(AlarmMain.scala:14)   at
>   com.ptnj.streaming.AlarmMain.main(AlarmMain.scala) Caused by:
>   java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext
>   Serialization stack:
>     - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.SparkContext, value: org.apache.spark.SparkContext@5fb7183b)
>     - field (class: com.ptnj.streaming.alertJob.InstanceAlertJob$$anonfun$1, name: sc$1,
>   type: class org.apache.spark.SparkContext)
>     - object (class com.ptnj.streaming.alertJob.InstanceAlertJob$$anonfun$1, ) 
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
>   ... 14 more

And I have never seen this situation before. Each example shows that broadcast variables would be create in output operation function but not transformation function, so is that possible?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: I tried my best to help here, but still think your question is hard to read. I wonder for example if you really need **both** stacktraces. Wouldnt it be better to just mention your first problem briefly. Also: consider providing some code, as in [mcve].